# c# .net: referenced dlls, do the reference paths have to remain relevant after compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm wondering, if I reference a dll in my c# project and then compile the project, does the compiled dll remain dependent on the existence of the referenced dll?

For example, say I had referenced a dll `c:/myLib/some.dll`. Once I've compiled my class library that references this do I need to keep the reference dll in that location or is the dependency merged with the class library I'm creating?

I ask because I'm creating a project that references a set of dlls which will inevitably be migrated into a project directory in the future (haven't do so yet as I'm still unclear on dll usage).

Thanks/

Comment: No, this library should just be discoverable at runtime (for example placed in the same folder with main application or at another path runtime will look for dlls at). It should not be present at the same path you add reference to it from. Also if you set `Copy Local` of that dependency to `true` - Visual Studio will copy it to output folder for you.

Comment: Maybe.  It depends how you add the dll to your project.  When adding a dll I usually recommend leaving the dll where it is located and the use "Add Existing Item" and browse to where dll is located.  The compiler will then copy the dll to the project bin folder whenever the dll gets updated.  So in this case the reference paths are relevant.   If you copy the dll to a different location inside the project then the paths do not have to remain relevant.  When debugging having the paths allow source code (not assembly language) to be visible while stepping through code.